# how do i configure stableloader in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

when i run a simple program i got this

```
Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@1cd2e5f; Unable to find property 'hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb' on class: org.apache.cassandra.config.Config
Invalid yaml; unable to start server.  See log for stacktrace.
```

can anybody tell me why so?

Comment: This will be like a comment or a statement not code?

Comment: its about code ,, how do i configure..

Comment: Can we see the said log and stacktrace ?